# Can a Rails Template Determine Which Controller Called It?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, view, controller

In my Rails app, I want to update the contents of a header element in my application wide layout and have that content depend on which controller is handling the request. For example, if UserController is handling the request, then the header element content could be "User Page", but if the PhotoController is handling the request then the header element content could be "Photo Page".  The solutions I've came up with (using content_for or setting instance variables) all seem to require code duplication and I'm looking for a DRY implementation.  Is there a Rails variable that I can use in my view that reflects the current controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `params[:controller]` variable to determine this, or if you want something longer then `controller.controller_name`.

Comment: What about which method in the controller ? ( 4 years later and still useful !!)

Comment: That'd be `params[:action]`